# Where did the children spend their time during X-Men 2?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, x-men-2

During *X-Men 2*, the school is attacked, and so the student body flees.  We follow one group for the bulk of the film, but there were others.  Specifically, I'm curious about the younger students.  During the battle, Colossus wants to go with our heroes, but is told instead to help the kids.  Then we don't hear from them again.

Where did the children go to after the attack?

Answer (score 2):

This is dealt with in the film's [official novelisation](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_2_(novelization)). In short, the soldiers don't actually know the *identities* of the children who were in the mansion and certainly don't have any remit to go on a cross-country manhunt to try to chase them down. After Peter Rasputin (Colossus) guides them to safety along the storm channel, it's likely that they simply dispersed to stay with any nearby families that were sympathetic, in precisely the same way that Rogue/Wolverine, etc stopped off at Bobby's house.

> ***The only alternative would be to widen the search parameters and try
>   to pick the mutants up when they emerged onto the surface. But that
>   would mean significantly degrading the resources available to monitor
>   the prime target, Xavier’s mansion.*** Again, given mission parameters,
>   not an option.
>
> ***Barring a miracle, any kids who’d escaped into the tunnels were pretty
>   much free and clear.***
>
> *Unaware of this, Peter Rasputin led his party into one of the long
>   tunnels burrowed deep beneath the estate. Its terminus was a thick
>   stand of woods outside Xavier’s holdings, a nature preserve. He had no
>   idea what would happen after that, or what would become of a score of
>   terrified, bedraggled children in their nightclothes, with no money
>   between them and no one close at hand they could trust.*
>
> *Right now, though, for Peter, that didn’t seem so important. He just
>   wanted to get them, and himself, out of danger, to a place where no
>   one would chase them or threaten them with guns. He wanted a breather,
>   time enough to gather his wits and take stock of both the situation
>   and his resources. Of the ultimate outcome, though, he had no doubt.*
>
> *Awful as things seemed now, in the end he was sure they’d work out all
>   right.*

That being said, at least one of their number is capable of walking through walls. There's a reasonable possibility that she emptied the nearest bank vault and that the kids spent the remainder of the film holed up in the [Emperor's Suite at Caesar's](http://www.vegassuitesource.com/hotels/caesars-palace/rooms-and-suites/caesars-palace-forum-tower-emperors-suites).